# How to call angularJS event on added items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm a beginner of AngularJS, and I cannot solve the problem of the title. If we push the button `changeText` in the following code, the text of the textarea will change. But this event doesn't happen if we push the button `changeTextNew` which is added by pushing another button addNewButton`.

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input name="widget.title" ng-model="widget.title"><br>
<input type="button" ng-click="setText()" value="changeText"><br>


<input type="button" id="piyo" value="addNewButton">
<div id="fuga"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.widget = { title: 'before' };

        $scope.setText = function() {
            this.widget.title = "after"
        }
    });

$(document).on('click', '#piyo', function() {
    $('#fuga').append("<input type='button'  ng-click='setText()' value='changeTextNew'><br>")
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sn512/guqjatt6/

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `ng-click` for the `addNewButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using jQuery together with AngularJS.

Try this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
        $scope.widget = { title: 'before' };

        $scope.setText = function() {
            this.widget.title = "after"
        }
        
        $(document).on('click', '#piyo', function() {
          $("#fuga").append($compile("<input type='button'  ng-click='setText()' value='changeTextNew'><br>")($scope));
        });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input name="widget.title" ng-model="widget.title"><br>
  <input type="button" ng-click="setText()" value="changeText"><br>

  <input type="button" id="piyo" value="addNewButton">
  <div id="fuga"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my current javascript code is written with lots of jQuery expressions. I just want to use AngularJS for a specific purpose (custom validators), and don't want to rewrite all. Especially, it's difficult to remove the following lines: 

        `$(document).on('click', '#piyo', function() {
     $('#fuga').append("<input type='button'  ng-click='setText()' value='changeTextNew'><br>")
        }) `   

Should I give up AngularJS in such a case?

Comment: In this case, you should "compile" HTML string with angular features before inserting it into the DOM. For this, you need to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service. I updated jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot.

Comment: @Saga873, If this answer is sufficient, please accept for future users with this issue.